# IBOutletCollections alternatives in OSX (2016 Redux) for custom radio buttons

Tags: macos, custom-controls, iboutletcollection

I'm trying to implement custom buttons as a radio button group. As I've found no way to customize radio button appearance (on/off/hover for each state), I've implemented them as custom image buttons (NSButton subclass). That part works fine. The issue is handling the states of each group of buttons and the corresponding variables determined by the groups (1 per group). IBCollections looks like  a great fit for this problem. But I'm writing a Mac app.

The few questions I can find on here on IBOutletCollections in OS X*  are a couple of years old. I can't even comment on them to ask since I lack the reputation points, thus the new question.

I did upvote the answers as they helped immensely as the blog posts on IBCollections I read didn't bother to specify them as iOS/UIKit only nor did XCode display any errors (SO HELPFUL! /sarcasm).

Has anyway come up with an alternative way to accomplish this? Separate outlets for each is madness for a group of buttons like these (or worse multiple groups). Can I implement them as an array for IB defined buttons with IBOutlets and IBActions?

*soon to revert to Mac OS (though it will capitalization challenged :)

Answer (score 1):

I won't claim it's an elegant solution, but I managed to solve my problem by grouping the custom buttons with `NSArray arrayWithObjects:` for each button group.

I added two methods to emulate radio button behavior (in this case for custom color buttons):

```
-(void)setButtonSelected:(NSArray*) theButtons toColor:(NSString*)color {
    [self clearAllButtons:theButtons];
    for (ColorButton *button in theButtons) {
        if ([button.color isEqualToString:color]) {
            button.state = NSOnState;
        }
    }
}

-(void)clearAllButtons:(NSArray*) theButtons {
    for (ColorButton *button in theButtons) {
        button.state = NSOffState;
    }
}
```

As my specific problem involved more than one group of buttons that required unique selections, I then added arrays for the each of the aligned options in the groups (columns basically).

```
- (void)clearColorConflicts:(NSArray*)theButtons forRow:(NSString*)row {
    for (ColorButton *button in theButtons) {
        if (![button.row isEqualToString:row]) {
            if (button.state == NSOnState) {
                button.state = NSOffState;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, it may not be an elegant solution but it solved my problem without IBOutletCollection.

I did look into NSMatrix but I wasn't able to use custom image button behavior (on, off, hover_on, hover_off) when I grouped the custom buttons as a matrix.

The column groups could be handled by the two original methods but I have additional steps for variable/defaults updating when rows/category selections are cleared by selection in another row. In hindsight I could have checked the state of each group after selection instead.

My problem may have been unique, but I'm posting this in case it helps someone else.

I'm not marking as solved as I hope someone has a better solution than mine.